# Closed form of $\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x}\, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions

I am trying to evaluate the integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x}\, dx, \;\;\; n \in \mathbb{N}$$

in a closed form.

I tried tackling it using Beta Form $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{t^{n-1}+t^{m-1}}{(1+t)^{m+n}}\, dt$ but unfortunately it does not coincide with formula of Beta.
Then I tried the sub $x=1/t-1$ to get the integral into a zero to infinity form but still I cannot get it into a form I wish. The only I could think of next is to apply incomplete Gamma or incomplete Beta. Any other hints? Could we attack it using contour integration when got in the form $0$ to $+\infty$?

Comment: Try the substitution $t = 1 + x$

Comment: @SimonS After applying the sub you suggest:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x}\,dx \overset{u=x+1}{=\! =\! =\!}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\left ( u-1 \right )^n}{u}\,du $$

Then I expand the nominator using the binomial expansion?

Comment: This is what I get:

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{1+x}\,dx &\overset{u=x+1}{=\! =\! =\!}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{\left ( u-1 \right )^n}{u}\,du \\ 
 &=\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{u}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}u^{n-k}(-1)^k \,du \\
 &=\int_{1}^{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}u^{n-k-1}(-1)^k\,du \\ 
 &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\int_{1}^{2}u^{n-k-1}\,du \\
 &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\left [ \frac{2^{n-k}-1}{n-k} \right ]
\end{aligned}$$

Pretty hard to do it , that way...

Comment: Be careful. There should be a $\ln$ in your expression.

Comment: An $\ln $ ? Hmm.. i must have lost it somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already seem to be quite familiar with both the [beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [$\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), allow me to

offer the following result: $~\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{x^{2a}}{1+x}~dx~=~\frac{H_a-H_{a-\frac12}}2~,~$ where $a>-\dfrac12~$ and $~H_{k-1}~=$

$=~\psi_{_0}(k)~+~\gamma~$ is the [generalized harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation), expressible in terms of the [digamma 

 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: Thank you.. that is very helpful... ! I accepted your answer since it helps me much more with the original question I am trying to solve. Although @Bombyx answer can provide me alternate path to the other question. That remains to be seen.

Answer (score 3):

You can treat this systematically using the following standard identity:
$$
\frac{x^{n}+1}{x+1}=x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}\cdots +1, n=2k+1
$$
and 
$$
\frac{x^{n}-1}{x+1}=x^{n-1}-x^{n-2}+x^{n-3}\cdots -1, n=2k
$$
So you essentially only need to integrate $\frac{1}{x+1}$ and various polynomial terms over $[0,1]$. But this should not be difficult for you. You can also establish a recurrence relationship if you needed.

Comment: Thank you... I had tried doing something like this... but failed in the first place. (+1)

Comment: There is something wrong with the second sum.

Answer (score 2):

With $I_0=\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x}dx=\ln2$
\begin{align}
I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x}dx
=& \int_0^1 \left(x^{n-1} -\frac{x^{n-1}}{1+x}\right)dx
=\frac1n - I_{n-1}\\
= &\ (-1)^n \ln2+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}{n-k}
\end{align}